# ReactRouterHashLink not palying well with material UI drawer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I am using the packages material-ui, react-router, and react-router-hash-link.  I want to have a material UI drawer (along an appbar) have hashlinks that scroll to specific bodies in the page, however whenever I do this, the scroll will happen, but when I close the drawer it reverts the scrollbar to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found a solution, for anybody who came across here, here is a solution:

The Drawer is expected to be **closed after navigation**. So, if you updated the drawer state on the `onClick` handler it would work as expected.

```
<Drawer
  onClose={this.handleToggleDrawer}
  anchor={"right"}
  open={this.state.openDrawer}
>
  <List>
    {links.map(({ text, to, icon }) => (
      <ListItem
        onClick={this.handleToggleDrawer}
        activeClassName={"Mui-selected"}
        to={to}
        button
        key={to}
      >
        <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={text} />
      </ListItem>
    ))}
  </List>
</Drawer>
```

```
handleToggleDrawer = () => {
  const { openDrawer } = this.state;
  this.setState({ openDrawer: !openDrawer });
}
```